# html-webpack-plugin not working with webpack-dev-server

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server, html-webpack-plugin

Webpack, you'll be the death of me.

html-webpack-plugin works fine in production.  The 'dist' folder is loaded with my html template and the bundle inserted. Ok cool.

However, webpack-dev-server doesn't do that.  It seems to be creating its OWN html page entitled 'Webpack App' and serving that.  **Where the heck does this come from?**  I need to be consistent in dev and prod so I can see what's up.  I'm merging the different configs using webpack-merge.

- webpack: 4.29.6
- webpack-cli: 3.3.0
- webpack-dev-server: 3.2.1
- html-webpack-loader: 0.0.5,
- html-webpack-plugin: 3.0.7

webpack.common

```
module.exports = {
    entry: [
        "react-hot-loader/patch",
        resolve("src", "entry.js")
    ],
    output: {
        filename: "bundle.js",
        path: resolve('dist'),
        publicPath: "/"
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: [resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules')],
                use: [{ loader: 'babel-loader'}]
            },
            {
                test: /\.s(a|c)ss$/,
                use: [{
                    loader: 'style-loader'
                }, {
                    loader: 'css-loader'
                }, {
                    loader: 'sass-loader'
                }]
        }
      ]
    },
    resolve: {
          extensions: [".js", "jsx"],
      alias: {
        actions:     resolve(__dirname, 'src', 'actions'),
        components:  resolve(__dirname, 'src', 'components'),
        lib:         resolve(__dirname, 'src', 'lib'),
        routes:      resolve(__dirname, 'src', 'routes'),
        store:       resolve(__dirname, 'src', 'store'),
        styles:      resolve(__dirname, 'src', 'styles'),
        test:        resolve(__dirname, 'src', 'test'),
      },
      modules: [
        resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules'),
        resolve(__dirname, 'src')
      ]
  },
    plugins: [
       new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
     new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
       "template": resolve(__dirname, "src", "index.html"),
       "filename": resolve(__dirname, "dist", "index.html"),
       "hash": true,
       "inject": true,
       "compile": true,
       "favicon": false,
       "minify": true,
       "cache": true,
       "showErrors": true,
       "chunks": "all",
       "excludeChunks": [],
       "title": "React Starter",
       "xhtml": true,
       "chunksSortMode": 'none' //fixes bug
     }),
     new CleanWebpackPlugin(['dist'])
    ]
}
```

webpack.dev

```
module.exports = merge(common, {
    devtool: "eval-source-map",
    mode: 'development',
    devServer: {
        host: 'localhost',
        port: 3000,
        open: true
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Webpack dev server does not write the files to a dist folder, it serves the bundle from memory. But if you use the contentBase option (which defaults to your current working directory), it will serve those files from disk. The in-memory files are preferred above the contentBase files though.

Comment: So, my question is now to get the html-webpack-plugin working with webpack-dev-server.  Does the contentBase option enable that?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like things have changed up a bit since I learned webpack a few years ago. It creates its own html file unless you tell it otherwise. So now do this:

```
npm i -D html-loader
```

set up these sections like this in your dev config:

```js
devServer: {
    contentBase: './dist'
},

...  

module: {
    rules: [
        {
            test: /\.html$/,
            loader: 'html-loader'
        },
    ]
    ...

    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: 'src/template.html'
        })
    ]
    ...
}
```

now your template.html file will work.